# Java - ' ) ' expected error

Tags: java, syntax-error

Bellow is part of a code I'm making  that calculates volumes. I'm getting the "' ) ' expected error" 2 times. First on -> `if (solidom.equalsIgnoreCase("esfera"){` , and the second one at -> `if (solidom.equalsIgnoreCase("cilindro") {` . Can someone help me? :/

```
private static double volume(String solidom, double alturam, double areaBasem, double raiom) {
double vol;

    if (solidom.equalsIgnoreCase("esfera"){
        vol=(4.0/3)*Math.pi*Math.pow(raiom,3);
    }
    else {
        if (solidom.equalsIgnoreCase("cilindro") {
            vol=Math.pi*Math.pow(raiom,2)*alturam;
        }
        else {
            vol=(1.0/3)*Math.pi*Math.pow(raiom,2)*alturam;
        }
    }
    return vol;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (solidom.equalsIgnoreCase("esfera")
```

should be:

```
if (solidom.equalsIgnoreCase("esfera"))
```

You have right closing parenthesis missing in your `if conditions`.

**PS:** You should really be using an IDE like Eclipse to write your code which will help you immensely to overcome these simple syntax errors.

Comment: You're welcome. As I noted above, using an IDE like Eclipse to write your code which will really help you.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans because that's what the professor recommends to use at the University. But I'm going to install it right now. Thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (solidom.equalsIgnoreCase("esfera"){
```

You missed parenthesis:

```
if (solidom.equalsIgnoreCase("esfera")){
```

Same for

```
if (solidom.equalsIgnoreCase("cilindro") {
```

It should be

```
if (solidom.equalsIgnoreCase("cilindro")) {
```

Comment: Thanks! Really fast answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the closed parenthesis at the end of the condition of the if statement on both of these lines.